# Word2Vec on sets of integers

Tags: nlp, word2vec

The purpose (and power) of Word2Vec is the context of the language (i.e., given a sentence like "I ate *blankword* for breakfast" we can assume that only a small fraction of our corpus, like eggs, salad etc.. might fit there).

I wonder if this idiom still works when we remove the context of the language and consider Word2Vec on sets. For example, consider the case where each person has some vector of integers associated to it, like [301, 285, 417,..], where this vector describes properties of that person. Clearly, the order of the properties does not matter.
We can assume that each person has at most 70 such properties. And that the entire corpus has about 500 properties. The goal is given some person, detect the list of k most similar persons, where k is some integer parameter.

Can we use Word2Vec for this task? On one hand, given a vector of properties, it seems that we can use Word2Vec with pretty large window size. On the other hand, this kind of contradicts the assumption that **only a small fraction of our corpus fits for any given word**.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption "only a small fraction of our corpus fits for any given word" is not an inherent precondition for applying these kinds of algorithms. It might be true in the common case – natural language, given usual word co-occurrence patterns – but word2vec & similar algorithms are often applied to other kinds of data that are only vaguely natural-language-like.

So the answer to "can we use word2vec for this?" is: yes, of course you can try. But only trying (perhaps with other tuning) and evaluating the results will tell you if the approach is beneficial for your specific data & goals.

Related thoughts:

- As a baseline which already aligns with much of your thinking, you could set word2vec & related "dense embedding" approaches aside for a moment, and just model your datapoints as sparse 500-dimension one-hot vectors of your (~about) 500 properties. You can then calculate things like cosine-similarity between these vectors as a simple, fast way to get a quantitative similarity between any pair, or find the top-*k* most-similar items. Finding the most common extra "on" properties in neighbors then becomes a very-simple recommender/basket-predictor.
- You can further refine that approach with direct dimensionality-reduction. Note that word-vector algorithms (like GLoVe or word2vec) are essentially methods for lossy-compression, that start with the giant set of all very-wide co-occurrence-within-a-context-window sparse vectors, and turn that into a set of per-word much-narrowed lower-dimensional dense embeddings. But you can do similar dimensionality-reductions on your 500d feature vectors, without necessarily bringing in all the other window/language/etc assumptions inherent to word-vector models. (And more generally, you may want to think of your task as recommendation/prediction rather than some adaptation of word2vec.)
- To the extent you do try word2vec-like algorithms, note that they most shine with large training sets & large vocabularies – typically tens of thousands to millions of modeled tokens. Your mere 500 unique tokens is quite a bit smaller, so you may need to try a wider-range of non-default settings to get the best results. One very vague & rough rule-of-thumb I use to: the model's dimensions (`vector_size`) should be no more than the square-root of the number of unique tokens. That suggests `vector_size=22` or less for your data, rather than the usual 100-400 values common with plentiful training data & large vocabularies. Similarly, other more-obscure parameters may also help when your co-occurrences or goals are different from usual natural-language applications. For example, in the Python Gensim `Word2Vec` implementation, a parameter called `ns_exponent` (fixed at `0.75` in many implementations) may vary; there's at least one paper suggesting applications like recommendation systems may benefit from a very-different value here.
- The idea of boiling a text of order-irrelevant tokens into a summary vector bares some resemblance to the word2vec-inspired "Paragraph Vectors" algorithm, specifically in its "DBOW" mode. (This is available in Python Gensim as the `Doc2Vec` model, with mode `dm=0`.) In this mode, context-windows & order is irrelevant, as the document-vector is trained to predict each word individually. Alternatively, as you've alluded-to, in usual word2vec implementations you can approximate a "full-document window" with a very-large `window` value. (In recent Gensim versions, there's also a non-default `shrink_windows=False` option that prevents internal optimizations that have the effect of overweighting closer words during training.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply.
Just to clarify, I agree that the property:
"only a small fraction of our corpus fits for any given word" is not directly related to the question of whether to use word2vec. I do think that it might neglect the use of negative sampling though. As in the case of negative sampling, you would assume that when choosing a word at random from the vocab, its probability of being related to the middle word is low. Which might not be true with a small vocab and a large window.

Comment: Yes, sometimes negative-sampling will choose a 'negative' word that's actually a plausible/common replacement for the target 'positive' word - and in those cases, that training micro-example will nudge the model to predict that word less often, despite its good fit. And further, that may happen more often in smaller models, or non-natural-language corpora, where the contrast between tokens isn't as stark. Still, I don't think it matters much in practice. Over all training micro-examples, over all random samples, over all epochs, the right correlations get reinforced moreso than any bad ones. …

Comment: It might delay 'convergence' a bit – as training is 'noisier' – requiring more epochs, but can likely reach a just-as-good end state if given the time. It plausibly might change optimal values of other parameters as well. For example, if tokens are generally less-contrasting, *maybe* a wider range of `negative` or `ns_exponent` settings worth trying, in case boosting 'positive' examples (which is sort of 'never wrong') suffers less interference from the random 'negatives'. But that should be tested/meta-optimized against real downstream evaluations like all other potential parameter tweaks.